# Division of Point in Elliptic Curve: Getting Back Point

Tags: elliptic-curves, algorithm-design, elliptic-curve-generation

Let $P=(x_p,y_p)$ be a point on elliptic curve $E (a, b) := y^2=x^3+ax+b$, for an integer $n$, there exists a point $Q=(x_q,y_q)=nP$ on $E (a, b)$.

If $(x_q,y_q)$ and $n$ are given, what is the algorithm to find  $(x_p,y_p)$?

**If possible provide code for python.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Elliptic Curves, we can compute the order of any point (and, in particular, the point $nP$; this is especially easy on the curves we actually use for ECC, because those curves typically have an order $hq$, for a small $h$ and a large prime $q$ (and the order of any point is a divisor of $hq$).

So, if $q$ is the order of the point $nP$, and if $n$ is relatively prime to $q$ (since we generally have $q$ prime in practice), we just compute $n^{-1} \bmod q$; we then have $(n^{-1} \bmod q)nP = P$; that is, multiplying $nP$ by the scalar $n^{-1} \bmod q$ gives us back the original point.

Comment: I am beginner so having some trouble to understand your answer, what is $n^{-1} \bmod q$? i understand $a \equiv b \bmod q$ where $b$ is the residue, but what does $n^{-1} \bmod q$ mean? is there any existing algorithm or software  where i can do that? I mean where can I find the code for Magma or sage?

Comment: @Andrew: $n^{-1} \bmod q$ is that value $m$ for which $n \times m \equiv 1 \pmod q$; we typically use the Extended Euclidean Method to compute such a value.  I am certain that both Magma and Sage has that built in (we quite often need to compute such things), however as I am unfamiliar with either of them, I cannot tell you the built-in to compute it.

Comment: To add to @poncho's answer it can be computed (when $q$ is prime) by using Fermat's Little Theorem: $n^{q-2} \bmod q$ will give you $n^{-1}\bmod q$. In SageMath, you can use *n.inverse_mod(q)*.